# Why isn't embeds index not working when sending a message

Tags: discord.js

I've attempted for a while now to try and get `msg.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })` to work however I keep getting `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

I should note that all code is in a module however all the proper resources are required so I'm at a total loss here, we are also running Discord.JS v12.2.0.

Here is what we have:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Test")
        .setColor("#00F0FF")
        .setTimestamp();
    client.log(JSON.stringify(embed.toJSON()), 1)
    msg.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }).then(() => {

    }).catch(err => {
        client.log(err, 2)
    });
}
```

Just another note, even if I do provide the `content` index it posts the message just without the embed.
I can also do `msg.channel.send(embed);` and it posts the embed, however I am needing to post multiple embeds without spamming discords api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using v12, but `{ embeds: [] }` is only in v13. You should either update to v13 or use the old way

```js
msg.channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: Your correct, I forgot to change version on the docs... Thanks!